# Unpatchify only supports reconstructing image with a uniform step size for all patches

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to patchify and unpatchify a sample image of size (2448,3264). I am using patchify library to make my patches. This code was taken from digital Sreeni youtube channel.

```
from patchify import patchify, unpatchify

img = cv2.imread(path,0)
patches_img = patchify(img, (256,256), step=256)
image1 = []
for i in range(patches_img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(patches_img.shape[1]):
        single_patch_img = patches_img[i, j, :, :]                   
        image1.append(single_patch_img)
```

For reconstruction of the above patches, I did this:

```
reshape = np.reshape(image1,(patches_img.shape[0], patches_img.shape[1], 256,256))
reconstruct = unpatchify(reshape,img.shape)
```

I am facing an issue while reconstructing it. When I reshaped the patches array and tried to unpatchify it. I am getting this following error.

```
NonUniformStepSizeError: Unpatchify only supports reconstructing image with a uniform step size for all patches. However, reconstructing 12 x 256px patches to an 3264 image requires 273.45454545454544 as step size, which is not an integer.
```

how to eliminate the step size error? where did I go wrong? any suggestions?

example image:
[image]

Comment: img = cv2.resize(img,(2304,3072),interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA) is perfectly working for step size of 256, the floating stepsize is not working for patchify.

Comment: So I think we should make our image size perfectly divisible to the step size.

Comment: Just wondering if there is any other way? instead of resizing it to make it perfectly divisible???